# Is there a simpler way to do this modulo operation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Question is:

> $38^7 \pmod{3} \equiv $ ?

I do this:

$38^7 \pmod 3 \equiv [(38 \pmod{3})^7]\pmod{3} \equiv [2^7] \pmod{3} \equiv 128 \pmod{3} \equiv 2$

Is there a way to do this without manually calculating $2^7$? I am worried about encountering a problem with a greater number raised to a higher power

Comment: You can use Fermat's little theorem to reduce the size of the power.

Comment: Actually there's an error in your calculation. $2^7=128$, but you put that $2^7=32$.

Comment: Alternatively, you could reduce modulo 3 iteratively.

Answer (score 5):

$38 \equiv -1 \mod 3$

$(-1)^7 \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$